# Is there any way to serve a private static file from amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have been playing around a little with amazon s3 as a storage backend and I noticed that you can now serve static websites on s3.

I tried uploading a simple site and it worked well, but I thought it would be great if you could set the files to private and generate a signed url to view the site.

Unfortunately, it seems that generating a signed url for the index page allows you to view that page, but predictably enough all the images are missing as they are set to private and so require there own signed url.

As I am new to s3 and amazon services I wondered if anyone else had managed a private site from s3 and or using s3 with a combination of other amazon services(cloudfront etc)

Comment: First of all, you will kill the objective of the website if you give it a private access. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find out how to do the same thing to keep the site private during development. I think this is not possible with S3. Someone has the same question in the AWS forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=81688

Bottom line: "I'm afraid you will need to host the website outside of S3 until you are ready to go public."